# What is the exact coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(2+x^3+x^6)^{10}$?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(2+x^3+x^6)^{10}$?

I figure you need to pick $x^3$ 4 times so $C(10,4)$...but what happens with the other numbers/variables???

Can someone explain to me how this is done properly?
Thanks.

EDIT:
$(x + y)^n = C(n,k) \cdot x^{n-k} \cdot y^k$

EX: Find the term for $x^5$ in $(5-2x)^8$
Answer: $C(8,5) \cdot (-2)^5 \cdot 5^3$

How can I use this info to solve a polynomial based question such as the featured?

### **Answer:**

To sum up all information provided by everyone (Thanks!!!):

$(C(10,4) * 2^6) + (C(10,2) * 2^8) + (C(10,1) * C(9,2) + 2^7) = 71040 $

Comment: Are you familiar with multinomial expansion?

Comment: You could also pick $x^6$ twice and then 2 eight times.

Comment: $2^{8} * x^6 * x^6 = 2^{8} x^{12}$

Comment: @SpamIAm Doesn't that add up to 12? n = 10

Comment: My mistake, I meant pick 2 eight times.

Comment: How about in combinational terms? If i wrote that as my answer it would be marked incorrect.  I'm looking for an answer such as $C(10,4) * x^6 * 2^4$ but I'm pretty sure this is incorrect...

Comment: See my edit example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: $x^{12} = x^6 x^6 = x^3 x^3  x^3 x^3 = x^3 x^3 x^6$

How many ways to pick $x^6 x^6$? Everything that's not an $x$ term is a multiplier of $2$. This would be $2^8 {10 \choose 2}$ for a total of $10$ elements.

For four $x^3$ there would be $10 \choose 4$ ways to pick.

Hint 2: For $x^3 x^3 x^6$ there are $10$ ways to choose the $x^6$, $10-1 \choose 2$ ways to pick  $x^3$.

Hopefully you can figure out the final sum of the three cases from here.

Comment: Would this be identical to $C(10,4) * 2^6$?

Comment: @user134788 no.

Comment: Why not? I'm picking 4 of x^3 and 6 of 2... Would that not result in the same answer?

Comment: @user134788 There are multiple ways of adding up to 12. See the first line.

Comment: Right, so when picking four $x^3$, I would then pick 2 how many times? 6? That also adds up to 10.

Comment: @user134788 yes, for a total of 10 elements.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense now.  Above you said no when I asked if it would result in the same answer lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can reach $x^{12}$ in the product from $x^6x^6\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$, which can be done in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways with a coefficient of $2^8$.

Or you can reach it with $x^6x^3x^3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$, which can be done in $\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{2}$ ways with a coefficient of $2^7$.

Or you can reach it with $x^3x^3x^3x^3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$, which can be done in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways with a coefficient of $2^6$.

$$\begin{align}2^8\binom{10}{2}+2^7\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{2}+2^6\binom{10}{4}&=64(4\cdot45+2\cdot10\cdot36+210)\\
&=64(1110)\\
&=71040
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1** Let $y=x^3$.

**Hint 2**  The coefficient for $y^4$ in $P(y)$ can be calculated by derivating $P(y)$ four times.

Comment: What is P(y)?...the power set?

Comment: @user134788 any polynomial in $y$ ;)

Comment: Set $P(x) = (2 + x^3 + x^6)^{10}$. Using the suggested substitution, we have $P(y) = (y^2 + y + 2)^{10}$.

Comment: It seems like you're just telling me how to expand the original equation manually and look at the coefficient.  I'm trying to skip all those steps and use the binomial theorum.  See my edit.

Comment: @user134788: No, that's not what N.S. said at all. Take the fourth derivative of $P(y) = (y^2 + y + 2)^{10}$. The constant term is 24 times the coefficient of $y^4$ (which is the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the original.)

Comment: @Kundor fourth derivative as in calculus?

Comment: @user134788: Yes, fourth derivative as in calculus. Recall that $P(y) = P(0) + P'(0) y + P''(0) y^2/2! + P^{(3)}(0) y^3/3! + P^{(4)}(0)y^4/4! + \dots$, so the coefficient of $y^4$ is $4! P^{(4)}(0)$, i.e. $24$ times the fourth deriviative of $P(y)$, evaluated at $0$. This is not necessarily a convenient thing to calculate, however, so I personally wouldn’t recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In combinatorial terms, you're looking for the number of partitions of $12$ that use only $0, 3$, and $6$ and have $10$ parts.  You then weight these partitions by multinomial coefficients.  There are $3$ such partitions:
\begin{align*}
12 &= 6 + 6 + 0 + \cdots + 0\\
&= 6 + 3 + 3 + 0 + \cdots + 0\\
&= 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 0 + \cdots + 0 \, .
\end{align*}
These partitions correspond to the terms
\begin{align*}
x^6 * x^6 * 2^8 &= 2^8 x^{12}\\
x^6 * x^3 * x^3 * 2^7 &= 2^7 x^{12}\\
x^3 * x^3 * x^3 * x^3 * 2^6 &= 2^6 x^{12} \, .
\end{align*}
Now we observe that the number of ways each of these can be chosen is $\binom{10}{8,2}$, $\binom{10}{7,2,1}$, $\binom{10}{6,4}$ ways.  So it looks to me that the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is
$$
\binom{10}{8,2} 2^8 + \binom{10}{7,2,1} 2^7 + \binom{10}{6,4} 2^6 \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\pars{2 + x^{3} + x^{6}}^{10}&=
\sum_{n_{1},n_{2},n_{3} = 0 \atop {\vphantom{\Large A}n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} = 10}}
{10! \over n_{1}!\,n_{2}!\,n_{3}!}\,2^{n_{1}}\pars{x^{3}}^{n_{2}}\pars{x^{6}}^{n_{3}}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n_{1},n_{2},n_{3} = 0 \atop {\vphantom{\Large A}n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} = 10}}
{10! \over n_{1}!\,n_{2}!\,n_{3}!}\,2^{n_{1}}x^{3n_{2} + 6n_{3}}
\end{align}

> $$
> x^{12}\mbox{- Coeff.}=\left.%
> \sum_{n_{1},n_{2},n_{3} = 0 \atop {\vphantom{\Large A}n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} = 10}}
> {10! \over n_{1}!\,n_{2}!\,n_{3}!}\,2^{n_{1}}\right\vert_{3n_{2} + 6n_{3} = 12}
> $$

Since $n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} = 10$ and $3n_{2} + 6n_{3} = 12$ we'll have:
$$
\pars{~n_{2} = -2n_{1} + 16 \geq 0\quad\imp\quad n_{1} \leq 8~}
\ \mbox{and}\
\pars{~n_{3} = n_{1} - 6 \geq 0\quad\imp\quad n_{1} \geq 6~}
$$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large x^{12}\mbox{- Coeff.}}&=\sum_{n_{1} = 6}^{8}
> {10! \over n_{1}!\,\pars{16 - 2n_{1}}!\,\pars{n_{1} - 6}!}\,2^{n_{1}}
> \\[3mm]&={10! \over 6!\,4!\,0!}\,2^{6}+
> {10! \over 7!\,2!\,1!}\,2^{7}+
> {10! \over 8!\,0!\,2!}\,2^{8}
> \\[3mm]&=2^{6}\pars{10\times 3\times 7 + 10\times 9\times 4\times 2 + 45\times 4}
> =2^{6}\pars{210 + 720 + 180}
> \\[3mm]&= 64\times 1110 = \color{#00f}{\large 71040}
> \end{align}